# Jpeg 2000 and .net

Tags: .net, activex, jpeg2000

I working in a activex control using .net for load it in a ie website. I need read a jpeg 2000 file but i don't want use a 3rd party dll because this will cause dependencies or embedding it make my dll very big. Anyone have idea where i can find a class .cs for  embedded on my project, i need only read file, no write only read.

Comment: So you're going to require the user to have .NET installed *and* install an ActiveX?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this project](http://csj2k.codeplex.com/), which contains a C# JPEG2000 decoder.  (Although it's still under development)

Comment: Available as NuGet here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CSJ2K/

Comment: Unfortunately, saving of the JPEG2000 file doesn't work correctly as of version 3.0; see https://github.com/cureos/csj2k/issues/11 .